# How to change password in brand new Unix user

Tags: rhel, users, passwd

First ever question for me. Straight to the point. I've added a user:

```
sudo useradd -m _homedir_ _username_
```

Tried all of these but nothing worked:

```
passwd _username_

chpasswd username: _password_

usermod -p _password_ _username_
```

I'm still unable to login directly but login works fine using

```
su -l username
```

Via root login.
This is the entry on the /etc/passwd file

***sftp_raes:x:11114:500:SFTP trasnfer ad-hoc user:/apps/data:/bin/bash***

PS. Passwd seems not to detect digits, always prompting 'less then 1 digit error
[image: error using passwd - digits undetected]

Comment: "digits" refers to a number (i.e. 0-9). Are you sure you're entering at least one number (and not using the numpad)?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: The original Question and title are answered in the original Answer below. The updated Question contains the correct command and is answered here in the updated Answer.

**Updated Answer**

A digit is a number (i.e. 0-9). `The password contains less than [n] digits` means your password requirements require at least `n` digits.

**Original Answer**

To change the password for another user, run this as a root user:

`passwd myusername`

Then you're prompted to input the password. See `man passwd` on your system, or use the following link [online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd).

Comment: or better, `man passwd` *on your RHEL system* (as the OP is using RHEL)

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, I still haven't settled on a preferred method of saying "use `man`, or use this link". I chose a link whose manpage matches my manpage (CentOS). Will try to edit the answer a bit.

Comment: Indeed, it's been [a discussion for a couple years](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3710/117549)

Comment: Thanks @KevinKruse but all commands I listed in the post were performed as root. Passwd in particular is giving me 'less then One digit error' due to the undetected digits while trying to set _password_

Comment: @user3405492 your post indicates you used `passwd mypassword`, not `passwd myusername`. After that, you will be prompted for a password but the characters will not be displayed on the terminal. If you are still having issues, please show what displays on the terminal after you use `passwd myusername`

Comment: I can't tell from your question, are your providing the password as an argument on the command line or interactively with the password command?

Comment: My bad, Sorry @Kevin. Post edited, providing screenshot asap